# How to rid of extra spaces in array list Java

Tags: java

When I try to break up a string such as `10-5*6/2+20` to leave just the operators in a array list, it adds an extra two places at the start of my array list.

Why is this happening and how can I prevent it?

The more digits for the starting number, the more empty spaces added to the start of the list.

```
String sum = "10-5*6/2+20";
String numbers = "[\\d]"; 
String string = sum;
String[] splits = string.split(numbers);

for (int i = 0; i <  splits.length; i++)
{                   
    System.out.println(splits[i]);
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using regular expressions for this. You need a proper scanner, that recognizes numeric literals, operators, and white space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a Matcher and retrieve what you are interested in, instead of removing what you don't want:

```
String sum = "10-5*6/2+20";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\D").matcher(sum); //keep non digit characters
while (m.find()) {
  System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Comment: this still leaves two spaces at the front of the operation

Comment: and shouldn't it be //d for non digits

Comment: @Rach no `\\d` is for digits and `\\D` is for non digits. Here instead of splitting on digits, I iterate over each non-digit item. There should not be any space (I have tested it on your example and it works as expected, returning [-, *, /, +] without any "blanks").

Comment: i copy and pasted the code into eclisps and it only outputted numbers for me ??

Comment: @Rach you are absolutely right - I guess I need some sleep! Editing now.

Comment: haha its fine, but it now still puts out the white spaces sadly, having to try and count the first number length and move the operators the long winded ways

Comment: @Rach See my edit. It should work now - sorry for the bad code previously,